# Eclipse CDT: passing multiple program arguments with same file extension

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I want to input a bunch of image files from the same folder and apply them the same operation inside a for-loop. I defined main as `int main(int argc, char** argv)` have this for-loop:

```
for(int i=1; i < argc; ++i)
{
   // do something here
}
```

In Eclipse CDT (Neon), under Run configurations > Arguments, I'm entering the paths of images that I want to process. It works when I explicitly give a list of images like `img1.jpg img2.jpg ...` however it doesn't work when I give try to run it on all the image files with a certain extension such as `dataset/*.jpg`.

Is there a workaround for this? Thanks.

Comment: I doubt if this can be fixed because it is the shell that expands the file names before the program gets the arguments.

Comment: The * expanding to the corresponding file names is a shell feature. So I see low probability on what you ask for. You can just copy-paste what your shell gives, no ? Damned, a few seconds late, because I wanted to suggest an intermediate mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a workaround for this?

The two most obvious ones that come to mind are:

1. Run the program from a terminal instead of from inside Eclipse.
2. Modify the program to take just the directory name as the argument, and have it iterate over the files in the directory.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to avoid the option 1 so that I don't have to switch back and forth between terminal and Eclipse. Option 2 is more feasible for me.